# NPM post-install, CA certificates, and Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, npm

#### TLDR;

Is it possible, in a Windows environment, to set `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` in a way that works with NPM packages' post-install scripts, without making system changes, configuration file changes, or changes that require admin-level permissions?

#### Details

This has been driving me nuts.

I added image optimization to our Webpack build process via imagemin, imagemin-webpack, and the various imagemin format-specific plugins.

All of the imagemin plugins have one thing in common -- during post-install, they:

a. Attempt to download a pre-built EXE.
b. If (a) fails, they attempt to build the EXE from source.

I.T. snoops on our traffic, so (a) fails due to the "self-signed certificate in chain" error when attempting to fetch the remote EXE. (b) fails because our studio is Windows-based, and we don't have all the various build tools installed to make that happen. It's also not reasonable to have them installed on every machine where `npm install` might be run.

I did some digging (thanks S.O.), found our company's CA certificate, added it to the repo, and was able to get (a) working with the following commands:

```
> SET NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=%cd%\ca.cert
> npm install
```

I thought I was home free at that point -- all I'd have to do is add this npm script to our package.json:

```
{
  "preinstall": "SET NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=%cd%\\ca.cert"
}
```

But that doesn't work. I'm guessing it's because there's a separate process involved, and the environment variable doesn't carry over to the other process.

Note that this *does* work, but is absolutely awful:

```
{
  "preinstall": "SET NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=%cd%\\ca.cert&& npm install imagemin-gifsicle imagemin-mozjpeg imagemin-optipng imagemin-svgo"
}
```

Is there a way to set this environment variable automatically in a way that works with NPM packages' post-install scripts?

I'd like this to be transparent to other team members so that they can just continue to `npm install` without any additional steps, system changes, or configuration file changes if at all possible. Some team members are not developers, so while they're used to running `npm install`, I don't want to introduce any additional complications. I super appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: I would try 'export' instead of 'set'. Set doesn't create permanent environment variables, it is only meant for use within a script, basically. No idea if it will solve this problem, but cannot hurt to try if you run into the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
npm config set cafile "<path to your certificate file>"
```

Comment: Yes, since this happens during post-install, npm's CA settings are not involved/honored. Only Node's CA settings are taken into account. According to other S.O. threads I've read, there is no known, documented setting to set a CA file specifically for the post-install process.